# how do I print Ä, Ö, Ü in python

Tags: python

Im writing a Crawler in Python and when I crawl german pages and write it into a txt file it doesnt write "Ö", "Ä" or "Ü", but \xD6, \xF6, ... instead

Any ideas how to fix that?

```
        ortschaften = list()
    text_file = open("Output_Brandenburg.txt", "w")
    for x in xrange(1,99):
        ortschaft = str(response.xpath('//*[@id="orte"]/div[1]/ul/li[' + str(x) + ']/a/text()').extract())

        ortschaft.replace("\xD6", "Oe")
        ortschaft.replace("\xF6", "oe")

        ortschaft.replace("\xAE", "Ae")
        ortschaft.replace("\xE4", "ae")

        ortschaft.replace("\xDC", "Ue")
        ortschaft.replace("\xFC", "ue")

        print ortschaft
        text_file.write(ortschaft + "\n")
        if ortschaft is not None:
            ortschaften.append(ortschaft) 
            pass
```

My Output for Example:

```
[u'Altreetz']
[u'Am Mellensee']
[u'Angerm\xfcnde']
[u'Annah\xfctte']
[u'Arensdorf']
[u'Bad Belzig']
```

Comment: Sounds like you are printing *containers*, so you only see the `repr()` of the contained strings, which are deliberately made ASCII-safe by showing escape-sequences for anything outside the ASCII range and for special characters. Don't print the containers, print the contents.

Comment: And how do I do that? Im sorry if this sounds stupid Im still learning.

Comment: Hard to say, we can't see your code, or your output.

Comment: Okay I edited my post, the \xfc is supposed to be ü

Comment: You need to make sure that the encoding you save your file matches the encoding of the characters you intend to write.

Comment: Is the result of xpath.extract() a list with a single element?

Comment: Yes I think so. I converted it though